# How to get a foreach loop variables values outside of the loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have following foreach loop:

```
$childDetails =array();
foreach( $result as $results ) {
    $applicationID = $results->booking_ID;
    $formType = $results->formType;
    $Student_name = $results->ChilldName;
    $payment = $results->Payment;
}
```

Now I want to get these variable values to be printed the out side of the loop

Application ID : here I have to echo `$applicationID`

Form type : here I have to echo `$formType`

Student Name : here I have to echo `$Student_name`

Payment : here I have to echo `$payment`

UPDATE:

I want to this because I have to echo the every variable and assign it to another variable.

eg : `$mail_body_guest_full .= 'Form Type is' . $results->formType;` how is that possible to use the above method to do this

If I echo `$childDetails`outside of the loop, it will print all of the variable values..
I want to print them one by one in different places of HTML..

how can do this?

Comment: print $result value and post it

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand  question , please explain waht you want to do ....

As i can see you have  loop , and now you can print out  every element  with "echo"  inside the loop.

Or

If you try echo  outside loop , you  will get  last elements from $result.

Comment: I have to echo the every variable and assign it to another variable. eg : `$mail_body_guest_full .= 'Form Type is' . $results->formType;` how is that possible to use the above method to do this.. check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to print it outside foreach loop

Do it as

```
<?php 
   $i=0;
    foreach( $result as $results ) {
    ?>
    Application ID :<?php echo $results->booking_ID; ?>
    Form type :<?php echo $results->formType;?>
    Student Name : <?php echo $results->ChilldName;?>
    Payment :<?php echo $results->Payment;
    $mail_body_guest_full[i].= 'Form Type is' . $results->formType;
    $i++;
    }?>
```

then outside the loop

you can print it as

```
echo $mail_body_guest_full[0];
```

Comment: I have to echo the every variable and assign it to another variable.
eg : `$mail_body_guest_full .= 'Form Type is' . $results->formType; ` how is that possible to use the above method to do this..